# Exclude category from get adjacent posts infinite loop in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Trying to figure out how I can completely exclude a category from an infinite loop code i found here: http://wplancer.com/infinite-next-and-previous-post-looping-in-wordpress/. There are some clues in the comments but i'm not sure how to actually integrate it into the code correctly. I've tried adding the category ID I want to exclude in this line, eg 'get_adjacent_post(false, '5', true')' but it doesn't seem to have any impact. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
<?php 
/**
 *  Infinite next and previous post looping in WordPress
 */
if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) ) { 
    previous_post_link('%link', '&larr; Previous Post');
} else { 
    $first = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">&larr; Previous Post</a>';
    wp_reset_query();
}; 

if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) { 
    next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post &rarr;');
} else { 
    $last = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); $last->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Next Post &rarr;</a>';
    wp_reset_query();
}; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by installing this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/ and then using the URL query style string code found on this page: http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress

Final code looked like this (make sure you have the plugin installed or it won't work):

```html
<?php previous_post_link_plus('order_by=post_date&meta_key=&loop=1&thumb=0&max_length=0&in_same_cat=0&ex_cats=24,11,10,8,9,12&ex_cats_method=strong&num_results=1&echo=1'); ?>
<?php next_post_link_plus('order_by=post_date&meta_key=&loop=1&thumb=0&max_length=0&in_same_cat=0&ex_cats=24,11,10,8,9,12&ex_cats_method=strong&num_results=1&echo=1'); ?>
```